# WF4 Service issue - ServiceManagement.svc

Tags: iis, workflow-foundation, net.pipe

having an issue with WF4 service running in IIS.

Error in event viewer is "Failed to invoke service menagement endpoint at 'net.pipe://[servername]//servicemenagement.svc' to activate service '/A_WorkflowService.xamlx' \rException; 'The message with To 'net.pipe://[servername]//ServiceManagement.svc' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. Check that the sender and receiver's EnpointAddresses agree."

people having the exact same issue, but no solutions

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/88f97778-8bd7-4952-9c3b-943114ddb2d8/failing-to-invoke-appfabric-service-management-service-endpoint?forum=wfprerelease

http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2010/08/28/appfabric-error-not-able-to-activate-any-of-the-hosts.aspx

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d2db4da0-b7a3-43d1-98e7-084960cec98e/wms-was-not-able-to-activate-any-of-the-hosts-backing-off?forum=dublin

net.pipe protocol is enabled on the web site and binding is also added in IIS. Basically everything that I found on the web is followed, but I still can't figure out what exactly is that error message trying to say.

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383422%28v=azure.10%29.aspx - the address of a service supposed to be  {scheme}://hostname:port//ServiceManagement.svc and in my error application bit is missing, but for what reason, no idea.

Thanks,
Pav

Comment: I have the same issue, I think the application piece is missing because the app is at the root of the webservice, so it's referring to it with a single /